# Userback.io Widge add data-toggle=tooltip to code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tesing Userback.io as a feedback tool -- one thing I ran into is that I use Bootstrap tooltips with data-toggle="tooltip" for branding. Userback has no control options for what they inject so the tooltip for them is the plain browser tip which breaks my branding design.

Is there a way I can append a data-toggle="tooltip" to their code? I tried appending it but I can't seem to find it, even if I wait for document ready. I test console.log using this and it comes back "undefined".

```
console.log($(".userback-button-se", "#userback_button_container").prop("title"));
```

Here is what they inject after loading their script;

```
<ubdiv id="userback_button_container" class="userback-button-container" data-html2canvas-ignore="true" loadtype="web" modal="true">
    <ubdiv class="userback-button userback-button-se" wstyle="circle" wicon="4" title="Help or Request">
       <svg>blahblah</svg>
    </ubdiv>
</ubdiv>
```

I'd like to inject the data-toggle="tooltip" into the ubdiv class="userback-button userback-button-se" line.

Answer (score 0):

Userback has JavaScript API that triggers when it adds its Dom to the document. What you can do is

```
Userback.on_open = function() {
    // add your Bootstrap tooltip here
}
```